# How do I add <tr> tag in a table using ajax_command_replace()?

Tags: 7, ajax

I am using `ajax_command_replace()` in an AJAX callback. It works fine to remove the full `<table>` markup, but I only need to add a row to the table after a form is submitted, when data exist.

What is the correct code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML wrapper you will be replacing sounds like it includes the whole table, so when you return the markup for the new table row, it will replace all the content in that selector/wrapper. You need to include the markup for your whole table including the newly added row, not just the new row.

Answer (score 0):

[`ajax_command_replace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_replace/7.x) is the function to replace elements from HTML markup. The first argument it accepts is the selector for the elements to replace, which means that if that selector is also for a `<table>` element, that element will be replaced.

To add a row into a table, you need either [`ajax_command_append()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_append/7.x) or [`ajax_command_prepend()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_prepend/7.x). For example, given the following markup, `ajax_command_append('#contacts', $row)` would add `$row` at the table bottom, and `ajax_command_prepend('#contacts', $row)` would add `$row` at the top. (The example markup has been taken from [HTML Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), on the W3Schools site.)

```html
 <table id="contacts">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```